# I keep getting an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a series of buttons that get their labels from the titles of the videos in a playlist.   Each time I run my code I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token class" error from the line starting with "var singleButton...."  I suspect it has to do with the fact that I'm trying to generate a div class but I'm not sure.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Any insights are greatly appreciated.

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var items = jwplayer().getPlaylist(),
      allButtons = ''; //empty str
      jwplayer().on('adError', function(evt) { console.log(evt); });
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var singleButton = ""<div class="buttons01"><button type="button">"" +     items[i].title + ""</button></div>"";
    allButtons += singleButton;  
    console.log(singleButton);
    console.log(allButtons);
}
   </script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: `var singleButton = ""<div class="buttons01"><button type="button">"" +     items[i].title + ""</button></div>"";` Doesn't look wrong to you? Even the syntax highlighting is having issues with it. Are you using an IDE for development? Or just a text editor?

Comment: I'm just using Sublime.  Is there an IDE you would recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var singleButton = '<div class="buttons01"><button type="button">' +     items[i].title + '</button></div>';
```

Instead of:

```
var singleButton = ""<div class="buttons01"><button type="button">"" +     items[i].title + ""</button></div>"";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var singleButton = "<div class='buttons01'><button type='button'>" +     items[i].title + "</button></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not escaping your string properly.

Change:

`var singleButton = ""<div class="buttons01"><button type="button">"" +     items[i].title + ""</button></div>"";`

To:

`var singleButton = "<div class=\"buttons01\"><button type=\"button\">" +     items[i].title + "</button></div>";`