# THIS message is keep poping up,,<SyntaxError: Unexpected token class('SheetConverter'>

Tags: javascript, email, google-sheets-api

I am making a code copy from spreadsheet to email however i am getting an error which keeps popping up

> <SyntaxError: Unexpected token class('SheetConverter'>

## my code.

```
function myFunction() {


  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('MAIL');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var range = s.getRange('C7:I24');
  var to = "example@ex.com" ;

  var body = "";

  var htmlTable = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(range);
var body = "Here is the table:<br/><br/>"
     + htmlTable
     + "<br/><br/>The end.";


   MailApp.sendEmail(to, 'Subject', body, {htmlBody: body})
}
```

Comment: " THIS message is keep poping up,"   whats the message? please edit your question and include the full error message in your question.

Comment: <SyntaxError: Unexpected token class('SheetConverter'> THIS IS THE MESSAGE

Comment: `SheetConverter` is an externallibrary - di you enable it>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33355065/1841839  <-- does this help

Comment: yes i enable it but.. this happend

Comment: @ziganotschka  i enabled it but it dosent work. and also <SyntaxError: Unexpected token class('SheetConverter'> this message keep poping up

Comment: Hello @jmk, you might find helpful my answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772484/send-email-from-google-sheet-as-a-table-without-using-sheets-convertor/56774647#56774647)

Answer (score 4):

There is a [bug report](https://github.com/mogsdad/SheetConverter/issues/15) with respect to v8 support with the SheetConverter library.  As a workaround in the short term, you could create the file yourself inside of your project and remove the library reference, copy the source code from [here](https://script.google.com/d/1kL7pHe3Ru9hCcc1YXJTdPCuPRo-rDzH9fi3--QF8TE7AxIrQoJXZht8A/edit?usp=sharing) and edit lines 58-60 to read:

```
function objIsClass_(object,className) {
  return (toClass_.call(object).indexOf(className) !== -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be bug with the SheetConverter library, only after Enabling New App Script runtime this error is being populated. Try disabling New App Script runtime.

In the Script Editor >> Run >> Disable New App Script runtime.

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Settings and untick this option:

- Enable Chrome V8 runtime.