# Google Scripting and Email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I have a Googlesheet with a table which is prefilled with data,

I would like to send a 'picture' of the summary/table in an email using scripting

Is there a way to get a preview of the table in the body of the email using scripting?

Thank you for any help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this task you can use [SheetConverter](https://github.com/mogsdad/SheetConverter).

- Follow these instructions in order to include this [library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/sheetconverter)
  directly to your project.
- However, if you come across with any issues the first answer of this
  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60315152/this-message-is-keep-poping-up-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-classsheetconve) will give you the solution you are looking for.

After you imported the library, use this code snippet to send a "screenshot" of the table in the body of the email. You can specify the range of the table here:

```
const range = s.getRange('B2:C10');
```

please also adjust the name of the Sheet, in the following example I use *Sheet1*.

**Code.gs**

```
function sendEmail() {
  
  const s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const conv = SheetConverter.init(ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
                    ss.getSpreadsheetLocale());
  const range = s.getRange('B2:C10');
  
  const htmlTable = conv.convertRange2html(range);
  
  const to = 'example@gmail.com';
  
  const body = 
     "Dear Sir or Madam, <br/><br/>" 
     + htmlTable
     + "<br/><br/>End of report." ;
     
  const subject ="This is a test";
     
     MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body, {htmlBody: body});
     
}
```

Comment: Just one more question if i may, within this script can i reformat the numbers to include () if a negative number and commas?

Comment: @Alexasks which numbers ?

Comment: within the prefilled table, for example in my google sheet they are layed out 85,985 but when it sends the email it is 85985 - also some numbers are seen as a negative (85,985) but in the email appearing as -85985

Comment: @Alexasks  Try to change both `text` and format in the `cell` to 85,985 and run the script again. It should capture the correct format.

Comment: Thank you, just looks like i am unable to have negative numbers within brackets ()